# Node websocket client side listen to Golang websocket server

Tags: node.js, go, websocket

I am trying to post messages using Golang websocket and listen on Node client side.

Here's part of code:

Golang:

```
func NewUpgrader() *websocket.Upgrader {
    return &websocket.Upgrader{
        ReadBufferSize:  1024,
        WriteBufferSize: 1024,
        CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
            return true
        },
}

func (s WebsocketHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    upgrader := NewUpgrader()
    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("websocket: could not upgrade %v", err)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "websocket: could not upgrade %v", err)
        return
    }

    go func() {
        defer ws.Close()
        for msg := range s.Messages {
            json, _ := json.Marshal(msg)
            err := ws.WriteMessage(1, json)
            if err != nil {
                log.Errorf("websocket: error sending message: %v", err)
            }
        }
    }()
```

By doing this I can get all the messages when I run the code below on Google console

`ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/ws')
ws.onmessage = function(msg) { console.log(JSON.parse(msg.data)) }`

And I add the same two lines code on my client side, now I got these errors

Golang side:

`INFO[0009] 400 GET localhost:8080/ws (0 bytes) id: 77b7355412f2ffcd
ERRO[0009] websocket: could not upgrade websocket: not a websocket handshake: 'upgrade' token not found in 'Connection' header`

Client side(browser console):

`GET http://localhost:8080/ws 400 (Bad Request)
Failed to load http://localhost:8080/ws: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch`

I tried to compare these two get request(Google console vs my client-side code). I found out that for google console there's a header `Connection:[Upgrade]`, but the header looks like this `Connection:[keep-alive]` in my client-side code.

Not sure if this is the reason why I can not connect these two, any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The first request is probably a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests). Check the request method, which should be OPTIONS, and handle that request first.

Comment: @Peter I used to handle the OPTIONS first at my golang part, but I am getting the same error which is 202 for options but still 400 for GET. Btw why do I do not have to go through the preflight request when using google console?

Comment: @CeriseLimón I am doing almost the same thing in my Angular controller . 

`import WebSocket from'ws';  
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/ws', {
    origin: "http://localhost:4000"
});  
ws.onmessage = function(msg) { console.log("Received message:", JSON.parse(msg.data)) }`

Comment: @CeriseLimón For server side it listen to `http://localhost:8080` and client side for `http://localhost:4000`

Comment: @CeriseLimón Tried this before. Also for the upgrader, it already returns true for all Origin. Anything I can add?

Comment: @CeriseLimón  It works when I used web browser client but fails on Node client. So yes, I was asking about how to fix it on Node

Comment: @CeriseLimón Client side console in question means the error I got from chrome devtools when I ran my angular code with node server. Google console is the result that I just use chrome devtools to setup websocket and it works